# java how to display all vowels in user input String

Tags: java, arrays, string

I'm trying to let user input a string then displays all the vowels found in the user input string, this is my code but it couldn't display the correct results.

If the user input: `I'm desperate`

The result should be all the vowels in the string: `i, e, e, a, e`

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Lab7stringvowels {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    Scanner input = new Scanner (System.in);
    System.out.println ("Enter a string:");
    String s = input.nextLine();

    char [] sChars = s.toCharArray();
    char[] vowels = {'a','e','i','o','u'}; 
        for (int j = 0 ; j < sChars.length ; j ++ ) {   
            for (int i = 0; i < vowels.length ; i++ ) {

         if ( sChars == vowels) {
             System.out.print(vowels[i] + "  ");
         }
       }
     }
    }
}
```

Comment: You need to check whether your input sChars contains any vowels. Right now, you're checking that the input is exactly the same as the vowels array.

Comment: Any reason why you don't use regular expressions for this?

Answer (score 4):

You should not compare the arrays directly to find the vowels, instead you must use the array name in combination with the indices from your for loop.

```
//Initialize your arrays

for (int j = 0 ; j < sChars.length ; j ++ ) {   
    for (int i = 0; i < vowels.length ; i++ ) {
        if ( sChars[j] == vowels[i]) {
            System.out.print(vowels[i]+ " ");
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I would start by writing a method to test if a character is a vowel (and you could use [`Character.toLowerCase(char)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Character.html#toLowerCase%28char%29) to ignore case). Something like,

```
public static boolean isVowel(char ch) {
    switch (Character.toLowerCase(ch)) {
    case 'a': case 'e': case 'i': case 'o': case 'u':
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

alternatively, you might prefer something like

```
public static boolean isVowel(char ch) {
    return "aeiou".contains(Character.toString(Character.toLowerCase(ch)));
}
```

Then you could test your input with a [`for-each` loop](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/guide/language/foreach.html) like

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Enter a string:");
    String s = input.nextLine();
    for (char ch : s.toCharArray()) {
        if (isVowel(ch)) {
            System.out.printf("%c ", ch);
        }
    }
}
```